# Incorrrect Merge, Instead of merging A to B I merged B to A in GIT LAB

Tags: git, branch, gitlab, git-merge

Instead of merging B (Branch) to A(Feature) I merged A(Feature) to B(Branch) in GIT LAB.
Here is a graphical representation of what I did.
I have this as below. With this the `"Branch A2"` merges into `"feature B2"` which is not what i intended. 
ISSUE: Now if i continue development, the Branch that will have to continue on is `"feature B2"` instead of `"Branch A2"`

```
Branch          A ----A1------ A2 <-- last commit
                 \              \  (merge into feature)
Branch(feature)   B -- -B1- - -- B2 <-- feature now contains Branch "A2" edits.
```

This is what I wanted. To merged `"feature B2"` into `"Branch A2"`; In this way when I continue my development it would be on the `"Branch A2"` and not `"feature B2"`

```
Branch(feature) B ----B1------ B2 <-- last feature commit
                 \              \  (merge into Branch)
Branch            A -- -A1- - -- A2 <-- Branch now contains "B2" feature edits.
```

What is the most clean way of fixing this so I can get Scenario 2 and continue working on `"A2"` Branch branch instead of `"B2"` feature branch?
Function wise, they both achieve the same thing whether you merged A2->B2 or B2->A2!
One way comes to mind is that I can rename the Merged branch and call it Branch A2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your changes were not pushed upstream, I think a

```
git checkout feature
git reset B1 --hard
git checkout branch
git merge feature
```

should do, where B1 is the commit before the merge.

> One way comes to mind is that I can rename the Merged branch and call it Branch A2

When you're "done" with feature anyway, that might even be the cleaner solution in your case.

```
git branch -d branch branch-tmp # Delete branch
git branch -m feature branch # Rename feature into branch
```

Comment: @ SVSchmidt, unfortunately, the changes were pushed to GITLAB already.

Comment: to which remote branch you pushed it?

Comment: @SVSchmidt. your solution rocks! The solution was pushed upstream in my case and deleting/manipulating the branch was the BEST way to keep my git history clean.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to revert to the commit before the merge in your branch (see [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)) and then redo the merge in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the benefit of others that may tread on this thread, here is my spiel. Note: All manipulations were done in ** `Local Repo` although you can do this in ** `remote Repo` in `Git Lab`. Once the merge was complete as shown in diagram 1 in original thread:

1. Create a new branch from the merged branch BUT name it as Branch A or any name that you initially intended it to be. `git branch <branch name e.g Branch A>`
2. Checkout the branch `git checkout <branch name eg Branch A>`. Now your new checked out branch and your Branch B would essentially be the same since there are no code changes since the last merge of branches.
3. Delete the branch where the merges were from both Local and Remote. `git push origin --delete <your remote branch name e.g feature A>`  and follow it up with `git branch -d <your local branch name e.g feature A>`
4. Confirm if this is what you want before pushing it to remote repo by `git branch --list` and then `git branch -a`. 
   No worries about history even if you delete these branches since when you push in your commits next time it will show that there was a merge of code and your most recent branch `Branch A` will have all your changes in it just as you merged branch. It works almost like pointers in C language. The variable name is gone but since you copied the pointer to another name, the address of your change is still intact.